# Simple jquery ajax append() not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I have correctly referenced jquery, version 2.1 (the newest one).  But nothing happens when I click "About".  I am running the code on a python (Flask) local server.  What am I doing wrong?

```
<div id="main">
  <div class="inner">
    <ul class="nav">
      <li class="active"><a href="/">Home</a></li>
      <li><a href="" id="about">About</a></li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</div>

<script>
  $(document).ready(function () {
    $('#about').click(function() {
      $('#main').append("testing");
    });
  });
</script>
```

edit: changed #about to `href='#'`, nothing changed

Comment: I don't see how this is related to Ajax.

Comment: if the `about` element is loaded dynamically then you may have to use [event delegation](http://learn.jquery.com/events/event-delegation/) like `$(document).on('click', '#about', function() {
      $('#main').append("testing");
    });`

Comment: It works fine for me: http://jsfiddle.net/Auqj4/. Note that the page reloads immediately, so the change is lost.

Comment: try putting '#' in 'a href' and test it

Answer (score 0):

Replace:

```
<li><a href="" id="about">About</a></li>
```

with

```
<li><a href="#" id="about">About</a></li>
```

Checkout this [Working version](http://jsfiddle.net/dhnh9/).

Answer (score 0):

The reality is, the page will be refreshed because you left the link href empty which means it points to the page itself.

Solution 1:

```
<li><a href="#" id="about">About</a></li>
```

Solution 2: stop hyperlink.

```
$(document).ready(function () {
$('#about').click(function() {
  $('#main').append("testing");
  return false;
});
```

});

Answer (score 0):

You need to prevent the default action of the link...

```
$('#about').click(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    $('#main').append("testing");
});
```